# Staging data in Snowflake: downloaded snowsql but still cannot use "put" command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Super new at data science and Snowflake

I'm trying to stage the data using the PUT command as directed in Snowflake documentation but it just says

"SQL compilation error: The command is not supported from the UI: PUT"

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you provide more information?  What is your command?  Where are you running SnowSQL?  Where is your data that you're trying to "put"?

Comment: if you are using the Web UI, you will get that message. But if you are running SnowSQL client it should not give you that message.

Answer (score 1):

PUT doesn't run in the UI, only SnowSQL. You can use the Load table feature in the UI, but it is very limited.